# rails3 : appending /app1 to apache virtual host url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed a Rails 3 application on a development server, and it can be loaded by using http://server:3000/

In our production setup, all applications are proxied by apache running on another server. All applications are to be accessed by http://prodserver/appX . CSS and javascripts need to be loaded when using apache proxy.

How do I revise routes.rb and change rails.root to use appX, without changing the application?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ProxyPassReverse configuration command in Apache and it will rewrite URL's so you don't have to change anything in routes.rb

Comment: Yes, I'm using ProxyPassReverse. Here is what I use: ProxyPass /appX/ http://192.168.1.16:3000/ retry=5 ProxyPassReverse /appX/ http://192.168.1.16:3000/ The application loads by using http://prodserver/appX, but all CSS and javascripts are missing....

Comment: Is your Rails app serving static files?  By default it only serves static files in development mode.  This setting will enable it, set this in your production config: config.serve_static_assets = true.  There are performance issues with this though.  It's probably better to use Passenger in Nginx or Apache (and then point your reverse proxy there instead).  Otherwise static file transfers will block your Rails process.  You may also consider using multiple Rails processes instead of just one.

Comment: The application is using Passenger. I'm totally new to Rails and Ruby, everything you said is alien to me. Are you implying that it has to be proxy'ed twice? Once by the production apache server, then by Passenger (on the development server), before loading the Rails application (on the development server)? Checked production.rb, config.serve_static_assets = false.

Comment: If you are using Passenger on your application server you shouldn't need to proxy it a second time and you shouldn't have to enable static file serving.  Why is your app running on port 3000?  That's usually where Mongrel or Webrick would be running.